# Geting error while make (mdb tool)

Tags: software-installation, compiling, make, configure, tools

I am trying to install mdb tools, I have installed everything it says in the guide at https://github.com/brianb/mdbtools but still not getting it to work. 
I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/src'
Making all in libmdb
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/src/libmdb'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/src/libmdb'
Making all in extras
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/src/extras'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/src/extras'
Making all in sql
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/src/sql'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/src/sql'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/src/sql'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/src/sql'
Making all in util
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/src/util'
Making all in bash-completion
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/src/util/bash-completion'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/src/util/bash-completion'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/src/util'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/src/util'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/src/util'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/src'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/src'
Making all in include
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/include'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/include'
Making all in doc
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/doc'
rm -rf html
mkdir html
cd html && \
    openjade -d  -t sgml ../install.sgml
openjade:E: cannot find "-t"; tried "-t", "/usr/local/share/sgml/-t", "/usr/share/sgml/-t"
openjade:E: specification document does not have the DSSSL architecture as a base architecture
openjade:E: cannot find "sgml"; tried "sgml", "/usr/local/share/sgml/sgml", "/usr/share/sgml/sgml"
openjade:../install.sgml:1:55:W: cannot generate system identifier for public text "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook V4.1//EN"
openjade:../install.sgml:2:0:E: reference to entity "BOOK" for which no system identifier could be generated
openjade:../install.sgml:1:0: entity was defined here
openjade:../install.sgml:2:0:E: DTD did not contain element declaration for document type name
openjade:../install.sgml:3:5:E: element "BOOK" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:4:10:E: element "BOOKINFO" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:5:7:E: element "DATE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:6:14:E: element "RELEASEINFO" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:7:8:E: element "TITLE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:7:21:E: element "PRODUCTNAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:8:11:E: element "SUBTITLE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:8:63:E: element "PRODUCTNAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:9:9:E: element "AUTHOR" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:10:13:E: element "FIRSTNAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:11:11:E: element "SURNAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:13:12:E: element "COPYRIGHT" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:14:9:E: element "YEAR" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:15:11:E: element "HOLDER" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:17:14:E: element "LEGALNOTICE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:17:20:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:23:78:E: there is no attribute "LINKEND"
openjade:../install.sgml:23:84:E: element "LINK" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:28:5:E: element "TOC" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:30:9:E: element "PREFACE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:30:16:E: element "TITLE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:31:8:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:32:87:E: element "PRODUCTNAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:32:365:E: there is no attribute "URL"
openjade:../install.sgml:32:411:E: element "ULINK" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:34:8:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:35:172:E: element "ULINK" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:35:270:E: element "ULINK" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:39:165:E: element "PRODUCTNAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:40:55:E: element "ULINK" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:44:13:E: there is no attribute "ID"
openjade:../install.sgml:44:19:E: element "CHAPTER" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:45:8:E: element "TITLE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:45:29:E: element "PRODUCTNAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:47:7:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:48:12:E: element "PRODUCTNAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:50:7:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:51:12:E: element "PRODUCTNAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:51:281:E: element "PRODUCTNAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:51:558:E: element "FILENAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:51:595:E: element "FILENAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:51:650:E: element "PRODUCTNAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:51:718:E: element "ULINK" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:53:7:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:56:26:E: element "CHAPTER" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:57:9:E: element "TITLE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:57:40:E: element "PRODUCTNAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:58:8:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:59:12:E: element "PRODUCTNAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:61:12:E: there is no attribute "ID"
openjade:../install.sgml:61:20:E: element "SECT1" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:62:8:E: element "TITLE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:63:7:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:64:177:E: element "PRODUCTNAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:66:7:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:67:82:E: element "PRODUCTNAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:70:23:E: element "SECT1" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:71:8:E: element "TITLE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:72:7:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:73:12:E: element "PRODUCTNAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:74:6:E: element "TABLE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:75:6:E: element "TITLE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:76:13:E: there is no attribute "COLS"
openjade:../install.sgml:76:16:E: element "TGROUP" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:77:6:E: element "THEAD" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:78:12:E: element "ROW" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:79:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:80:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:83:6:E: element "TBODY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:84:12:E: element "ROW" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:85:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:86:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:88:12:E: element "ROW" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:89:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:90:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:92:12:E: element "ROW" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:93:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:94:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:96:12:E: element "ROW" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:97:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:98:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:100:12:E: element "ROW" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:101:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:102:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:104:12:E: element "ROW" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:105:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:106:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:108:12:E: element "ROW" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:109:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:110:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:117:23:E: element "SECT1" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:118:8:E: element "TITLE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:119:7:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:122:7:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:126:24:E: element "SECT1" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:127:8:E: element "TITLE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:128:7:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:131:7:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:135:19:E: element "SECT1" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:136:8:E: element "TITLE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:137:7:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:140:7:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:145:27:E: element "CHAPTER" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:146:8:E: element "TITLE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:147:7:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:148:12:E: element "PRODUCTNAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:150:22:E: element "SECT1" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:151:8:E: element "TITLE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:152:7:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:155:6:E: element "TABLE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:156:6:E: element "TITLE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:157:16:E: element "TGROUP" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:158:6:E: element "THEAD" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:159:12:E: element "ROW" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:160:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:161:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:162:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:163:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:164:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:165:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:168:6:E: element "TBODY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:169:12:E: element "ROW" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:170:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:171:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:172:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:173:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:174:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:174:46:E: element "ULINK" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:175:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:177:12:E: element "ROW" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:178:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:179:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:180:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:181:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:182:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:182:80:E: element "ULINK" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:183:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:185:12:E: element "ROW" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:186:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:187:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:188:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:189:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:190:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:190:72:E: element "ULINK" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:191:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:193:12:E: element "ROW" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:194:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:195:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:196:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:197:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:198:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:198:70:E: element "ULINK" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:199:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:201:12:E: element "ROW" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:202:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:203:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:204:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:205:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:206:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:206:51:E: element "ULINK" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:207:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:209:12:E: element "ROW" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:210:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:211:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:212:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:213:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:214:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:214:48:E: element "ULINK" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:215:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:217:12:E: element "ROW" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:218:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:219:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:220:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:221:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:222:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:222:48:E: element "ULINK" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:223:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:225:12:E: element "ROW" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:226:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:227:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:228:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:229:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:230:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:231:14:E: element "ENTRY" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:238:26:E: element "CHAPTER" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:239:8:E: element "TITLE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:240:7:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:241:12:E: element "PRODUCTNAME" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:243:17:E: element "SECT1" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:244:8:E: element "TITLE" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:245:7:E: element "PARA" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:247:7:E: element "SCREEN" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:248:7:E: element "PROMPT" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:248:29:E: element "USERINPUT" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:249:7:E: element "PROMPT" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:249:29:E: element "USERINPUT" undefined
openjade:../install.sgml:250:7:E: element "PROMPT" undefined
openjade:I: maximum number of errors (200) reached; change with -E option
Makefile:606: recipe for target 'install.tgz' failed
make[1]: *** [install.tgz] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rhs/Desktop/mdbtools-0.6pre1/mdbtools/doc'
Makefile:473: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: is this the complete output of make or only the last 6 lines?

Comment: I have just updated @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann :)

Comment: there seems to be some error when make runs openjade: `openjade -d  -t sgml ../install.sgml`, the errors are the next three lines. hopefully you can solve the problem with this info.

Comment: Unless you're installing from source for religius reasons (or because you want the bleeding-edge version of `mbdtools`), you could `apt-cache search mdbtools` and `sudo apt-get install` one of those.